# Flex Image variable in ActionScript, set the source(url), get it to create the BitmapData?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have an Image member variable in a class. I can set the myImage.source(url), and if that 
image is added to the displayList, then I can get the BitmapData of the image.

But, I wont be adding myImage to the display. I want to get it to create the Bitmap/BitmapData and then use references to that Image object at a later stage.

This is basically what I'm trying;

```
var urlString:String = "file:///C:/assets/images/logo.png";
myImage.source = urlString;
// Only after its added to the stage does it get created as an image so that i can 
// access Bitmap data
this.addChild(myImage);
// I want to replicate this in ActionScript, without displaying it at this point
```

I have tried numerous things, but every example depends on the Image being added to the 
displayList first. This post is now more of a last, not a first, resort!! :-)
Brian

**UPDATE:**

Needed to load the image with a Loader at the start. Couldn't find a way around this.

I'm just gonna use the BitmapData as the single reference to share among the images in the 
application - although  Flash Player 10.1 and AIR 2.5 have performance enhancements around 
the creation of multiple Bitmap objects that use the same BitmapData:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS4bebcd66a74275c3-576ba64d124318d7189-7ff9.html

Example of what I did:

```
private var myBitmapData:BitmapData;

            protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                var urlString:String = "file:///C:/assets/images/client_logo.png";

                var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlString);
                var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
                ldr.load(req); 
                ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileLoadComplete);
                ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);               
            }

            private function onIOError(event:IOErrorEvent):void{
                trace(event.text);
            }

            private function fileLoadComplete(event:Event):void
            {
                var ldr:Loader = Loader(event.target.loader);
                var bitmap:Bitmap = Bitmap(ldr.content);
                myBitmapData = bitmap.bitmapData;

                displayImage1.source = new Bitmap(myBitmapData);        
                displayImage2.source = new Bitmap(myBitmapData);
            }
```

Comment: it seems like problem of preloading , not of adding to stage. try to catch a full `load` event , may be after that you'll be able to use its `bitmapdata `

Comment: Thanks for heads up on load. Needed to go that route in the end. UPdated question (with solution I'm gonna use)

Comment: Great! So what's problem now?